# What is a good thesaurus and taxonomy library for Python?

Tags: python, taxonomy, thesaurus

Can you recommend a good Python library to get thesaurus and taxonomy of a given word?

Synonym:

```
>>> print get_synonym('image')
['picture', 'photo']
```

Taxonomy:

```
>>> print get_taxonomy('baseball')
['sports']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pywordnet](http://osteele.com/projects/pywordnet/), now part of [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. pywordnet works great. just one extra question, is there any good library to get pluralize words in python?

Comment: I knew a library `inflect` can get plural

Answer (score 2):

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)

### Installation

You might need superuser rights for that:

```
$ pip install nltk
```

### Usage

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

>>> wn.synsets('dog')
[Synset('dog.n.01'), Synset('frump.n.01'), Synset('dog.n.03'), Synset('cad.n.01'), Synset('frank.n.02'), Synset('pawl.n.01'), Synset('andiron.n.01'), Synset('chase.v.01')]

>>> wn.synset('dog.n.01').definition()
u'a member of the genus Canis (probably descended from the common wolf) that has been domesticated by man since prehistoric times; occurs in many breeds'

>>> wn.synset('dog.n.03').definition()
u'informal term for a man'

>>> baseball = wn.synset('baseball.n.01')
>>> sport = wn.synset('sport.n.01')
>>> picture = wn.synset('picture.n.01')

>>> sport.path_similarity(baseball)
0.16666666666666666

>>> sport.path_similarity(picture)
0.06666666666666667
```